# (H2O.ai) Does column name or order matter when an estimator predicts on data set?

Tags: python, h2o

Do `h2o` estimators need to have the input data set have the same column names that they were trained on (regardless of if some columns were ignored) or is it the order that matters (in which case, can the ignored columns be replaced with other data)?

Eg. When predicting on a data set with an `h2o` model, suppose the training frame for the a `DRF` model in the `h2o flow` UI was of the form:

```
fa | fb | fc | meta_a | meta_b | response
---------------------------------------
fa1| fb1| fc1| meta_a1| meta_b1| response1
fa2| fb2| fc2| meta_a2| meta_b2| response2
....
```

where I specify for the flow UI to ignore the meta_... columns.

Now say I load that model in python and want to predict with it on a new data set `frame_in` like:

```
est = h2o.load_model('/path/to/exported/model/file')
preds = est.predict(frame_in)
```

Where frame_in is a `pandas` dataframe of the form:

```
Fa | Fc | Fb | meta_c | meta_d | response
---------------------------------------
fa1| fb1| fc1| meta_a1| meta_b1| response1
fa2| fb2| fc2| meta_a2| meta_b2| response2
....
```

where the actual column names have been changed so fa=Fa, fb=Fb, fc=Fc (though they represent to same features) and the meta_... features are totally different data.

I imagine in this case there will be an error, but for which reason? The ordering of the columns (which again makes me ask if the meta_... columns that were ignored during training can then be totally different data here) or the changes in the column names? Is there any documentation that clarifies this (looking [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/training_frame.html) I was not able to tell)? Thanks.

Comment: please add the python tag to your question, your question is specific to h2o and python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order does not matter. Only the names matter. See the below example that demonstrates this (sorry it is R, but the behaviour will be identical in Python: the only R-specific thing here is: a) using built-in `iris`; b) using `t(d)`, as otherwise I end up with a 4-row, 1-column, H2O frame.)

BTW, if you specify column indices, instead of names, the first thing H2O does is convert them to column names. (See the `m@parameters$x` output in the below.)

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

iris <- as.h2o(iris)

m <- h2o.randomForest(1:4, 5, iris)
m@parameters$x

d <- c(1.4,3.6,5.0,0.2)
names(d) <- c("Petal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Petal.Width")

test <- as.h2o(t(d))
test

h2o.predict(m, test)
```

P.S. regarding your example, you will need to rename (lowercase) the column names in your test data, so that they match the training data, and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments, `x` and `y`, can be specified as either column names or column indices.

- If you specify `x` as column names when you train the model, then the names at prediction time must also match, but they don't have to be in any particular order.
- However, if you specify `x` as column indices when you train the model, then order matters.

Comment: Where is the "name" or "indices" specification located in the `h2o flow` UI? When I trained the model through that interface, I do not recall ever seeing that parameter. Is it set a particular way by default? I ask because looking at the model's `.get_params` and `.full_parameters` fields in python, I could not find anything that would tell me what the model was expecting.